# Steam doesn't let me get into properties

Tags: lubuntu, steam

I've been having this issue with steam on lubuntu for the past month and still haven't found a way to fix it; as the video shows, anytime I right click a menu in steam that has a drop down, it goes right through it even though the item is highlighted (apart from the top right selections). I tried some changes in openbox and it didn't solve the problem. If anyone could help me that would be much appreciated!

The version of Lubuntu I'm on is 22.04 and I've installed the Kernal Xanmod. Besides that, I installed steam through the website rather then the terminal.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4v_-fm098n0
This is the video of me showing whats going on.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1480035/edit) and add more information about your system and explain in words the content of your video. For example include in your question: the version of Lubuntu and Steam you are using.  How was Steam installed, apt, snap, or by other means? Are you using Wayland or Xorg?

Comment: Lubuntu is just a Ubuntu Desktop system with the desktop, some apps & libraries changed (ie. GNOME, gnome-apps & GTK replaced with LXQt, LXQt/Qt5 apps & Qt5) but it's the release that matters, which you didn't specify.  A wallpaper on your video appears to show a *jammy* wallpaper image to me, but as that [wallpaper] exists on later releases too it doesn't tell us much. Also if 22.04 the desktop can be upgraded via *backports* so please just tell us.

Comment: The version of Lubuntu I'm using is 22.04, and, I installed a kernal by the name of Xanmod around two weeks ago. Besides that, the window manger I'm using is x.org; when I type echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE into my command prompt I get x11. Besides that, the way I installed steam was through the website, and, that let me to the app installer. Sorry for not giving the appropriate amount of information to help.

Comment: Can you boot to the previous (standard) Lubuntu kernel using the advanced menu of grub (hold down the SHIFT key while booting if the grub menu is hidden) and verify the problem exists with the default kernel?

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact same problem with my lubuntu 
Just solved it by going into Steam, Steam > Settings > Interface 
and tick "Enable context menu focus compatibility mode"


Sadly for me it doesn't fix sub dropdown menus, for instance I still can't uninstall games through steam

Comment: dude this is helping me, it also works for me for the dropdown now I could opt in for beta